Unable to save Tag name on Laravel and Vue Js Project
working with Laravel 10 and Vue Js 3 and I need save Tag Name on the table. I have following AdminController
 public function addTag(Request $request){
       return Tag::create([
            'tagName' => $request->tagName
        ]);
    }

web.php
Route::post('app/create_tag', [AdminController::class, 'addTag']);

and tags.vue file is
<Modal v-model="addModal" title="Add Tag" :mask-closable="false" :closable="false">
                <Input v-model="data.tagName" placeholder="Add Tag Name" style="width: 300px" />

                <div slot="footer">
                    <Button type="default" @click="addModal=false">Close</Button>
                    <Button type="primary" @click="addTag" :disabled="isAdding" :loading="isAdding">{{ isAdding ? 'Adding..' : 'Add tag' }}</Button>
                </div>
            </Modal>

<script>
methods : {
        async addTag(){
            if(this.data.tagName.trim()=='') return this.e('Tag name is required')
            const res = await this.callApi('post', 'app/create_tag', this.data)
            if(res.status===200){
                
                this.tags.unshift(res.data)
                this.s('Tag has been added sucessfully!')
                this.addModal = false
                this.data.tagName = ''
            } else {
                this.swr()
            }
        }
    },

</script>

but when I try to save tag name on the table I got following error msg on the inspect of the browser
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of component event handler 
  at <Button type="primary" onClick=fn<bound addTag> disabled=false  ... > 
  at <BaseTransition onAfterLeave=fn<bound animationFinish> appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="ease" onAfterLeave=fn<bound animationFinish> > 
  at <Modal modelValue=true onUpdate:modelValue=fn title="Add Tag"  ... > 
  at <Tags onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< 


how could I fix this problem?
my common.js
export default {
    data(){
        return {

        }
    },

    methods:{
         async callApi(method, url, dataObj ){
            try {
              return await axios({
                    method: method,
                    url: url,
                    data: dataObj
                });
            } catch (e) {
                
                return e.response
            }
        }
}

